# Message Broker integrate design with IBM MQ

Tags: jms, integration, publish-subscribe, mq, messagebroker

Requirements: Integration with IBM MQ(on-premises) and cloud application. The cloud application instance only can be connected via MID Server(on-premises)

Question:
What is the best approach for this integration requirement? Should set up a message broker in the mid server ( IBM MQ-> Message Broker Software@Mid Server, JMS Program- -> Cloud App OR

just write a program e.g. JMS API talk to MQ directly ( IBM MQ -> JMS Program@Mid Server -> Cloud App)

Comment: This question has multiple problems. First, you're asking for a software recommendation which is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. Second, you've got multiple questions instead of just one. You should either rewrite your question to conform to Stack Overflow guidelines or close/delete it.

Answer (score 0):

App Connect Enterprise (abbreviated as ACE, formerly known as IIB/IBM Integration Bus) is a message broker that allows you to create flows and integrate with MQ.  Here is [Link to AppConnect Info.](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/app-connect?lnk=STW_US_STESCH&lnk2=trial_AppConn&pexp=def&psrc=none&mhsrc=ibmsearch_a&mhq=AppConnect)